# how to clear all slices in redux toolkit?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am using redux toolkit for app state management. I created 4 slices in it and I want to clear all the slices when user click logout button.

I know we can dispatch 4 methods to clear each slice, but is there a way that can clear the whole store.

Comment: What about reloading the whole page (`window.location.reload()`)? That seems more robust - there's no chance of preserving unwanted component or Redux state.

Comment: Yes we can do it in web, but I want to clear it in react native app

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same action across multiple reducers with the `extraReducers` field in `createSlice`.
https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice

The following code example creates that action using `createAction` (but it could also be created by one of the four code slices).

```js
const clearAction = createAction('clear');

const initialStateForSlice1 = { /* etc */ };

const slice1 = createSlice({
  initialState: initialStateForSlice1,
  reducers: { /* etc */ },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(clearAction, () => initialStateForSlice1);
  }
});

const initialStateForSlice2 = { /* etc */ };

const slice2 = createSlice({
  initialState: initialStateForSlice2,
  reducers: { /* etc */ },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(clearAction, () => initialStateForSlice2);
  }
});

// and so on for each slice
```